# How to count distinct users on a 28-day sliding window - SQL Hive

Tags: sql, hive, count, sliding-window

I'm trying to calculate how many different users use an app in a 28-day window time.
For example, if I stand on feb-28, I want to know how many different users logged in the application.
The trick here is that I want to count them only once. Hence if user "22" logged 28 times, I want them to count just as one.

Besides, a user can only appear once per date.

```
select b.date, count(DISTINCT a.id)
from table a,
 (SELECT distinct(date), date_sub(date,27) dt_start
  from table) b
where a.date >= b.dt_start and a.date <= b.fecha
group by b.date
```

But it's not working

Example of what I want, with a 2-day sliding window:

```
Input
Day  Id
1    A
1    B
2    C
2    A
3    B
3    D
4    D

Result:
Day   Count(distinct Id)
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     2
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: What database are you using?  Hadoop is a parallel framework.  This is quite important because date functions vary among databases.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'm using Hive. I changed the title aswell. Thanks :D

Comment: And what are the two tables you are using.  You only show one table as input and the columns don't match what is in your query.

Comment: lol I'm dumb. There's only one table with 2 columns, date and Id. I edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct t.date, 
       (select count(distinct sub.id)
        from mytable sub
        where sub.date >= date_sub(t.date, 27) 
          and sub.date <= t.date) as distinct_users_27_days
from mytable t
```

Alternatively, an aggregation on self-join by window period:

```
select t1.date, 
       count(distinct t2.id) as distinct_users_27_days
from mytable t1
cross join mytable t2 
where t2.date >= date_sub(t1.date, 27) 
  and t2.date <= t1.date
group by t1.date
```

Comment: On the first answer solution I get:
"ParseException line 2:8 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'count' in expression specification"

While on the second one:
"Line 5:6 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '27'"

Besides you can't use > or < on joins condition with Hive

Comment: See edit. I missed an alias on *id*. If `cross join` does not work, replace it with comma. Possibly hive does not support `count(distinct...)`.